# Improving Shadow

Tags: rendering, shadows, depth-buffer, depth

I need to improve the shadows in my scene. At a first look they don't look too bad: 
[image]

They look awful when the camera gets closer to them, showing weird artifacts.

[image]

I would like to know what are the techniques to remove these artifacts, and make the shadows look better. In my case my engines uses forward rendering and atlas depth map for the shadows.

Comment: Probably irrelevant by now, but could this help: [Percentage Closer Filtering](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems/part-ii-lighting-and-shadows/chapter-11-shadow-map-antialiasing) ?